# ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to analyse a video using the video frames and the audio respectively and I have come up with a model that looks something like this 
[image: Model Structure](https://imgur.com/a/TRM2LFj[![Model Structure] 
Now, I have split my training data into two generators- one for video and one for audio. 
I had to further split the generators into two halves which is where I think I'm getting the error. Because the error log is huge and bloated with a huge array, I cannot post the entire thing here. You can find it [here](https://pastebin.com/tm7ZjEp0).

Basically the errors are

```
ERROR 1:
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.

First structure: type=tuple str=(array([[1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]]), array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]]))

Second structure: type=tuple str=(None,)

ERROR 2:
More specifically: The two structures don't have the same number of elements. First structure: type=tuple str=(array([[1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]]), array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]])). Second structure: type=tuple str=(None,)
Entire first structure:
(., .)
Entire second structure:
(.,)

ERROR 3:
ValueError: Unable to match target structure and sample_weight_modes structure:
  ['...', '...']
    to  
  ['...']
```

The VideoGenerator is as follows

```
class VideoFrameGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(
            self,
            rescale=1/255.,
            nb_frames: int = 5,
            classes: list = [],
            batch_size: int = 16,
            use_frame_cache: bool = False,
            target_shape: tuple = (648, 384),
            shuffle: bool = True,
            transformation: tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator = None,
            split: float = None,
            nb_channel: int = 3,
            glob_pattern: str = './videos/{classname}/*.avi',
            _validation_data: list = None):

        # should be only RGB or Grayscale
        assert nb_channel in (1, 3)

        # we should have classes
        assert len(classes) != 0

        # shape size should be 2
        assert len(target_shape) == 2

        # split factor should be a propoer value
        if split is not None:
            assert 0.0 < split < 1.0

        # be sure that classes are well ordered
        classes.sort()

        self.rescale = rescale
        self.classes = classes
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.nbframe = nb_frames
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.target_shape = target_shape
        self.nb_channel = nb_channel
        self.transformation = transformation
        self.use_frame_cache = use_frame_cache

        self._random_trans = []
        self.__frame_cache = {}
        self.files = []
        self.validation = []

        if _validation_data is not None:
            # we only need to set files here
            self.files = _validation_data
        else:
            if split is not None and split > 0.0:
                for cls in classes:
                    files = glob.glob(glob_pattern.format(classname=cls))
                    nbval = int(split * len(files))

                    print("class %s, validation count: %d" % (cls, nbval))

                    # generate validation indexes
                    indexes = np.arange(len(files))

                    if shuffle:
                        np.random.shuffle(indexes)

                    val = np.random.permutation(
                        indexes)[:nbval]  # get some sample
                    # remove validation from train
                    indexes = np.array([i for i in indexes if i not in val])

                    # and now, make the file list
                    self.files += [files[i] for i in indexes]
                    self.validation += [files[i] for i in val]

            else:
                for cls in classes:
                    self.files += glob.glob(glob_pattern.format(classname=cls))

        # build indexes
        self.files_count = len(self.files)
        self.indexes = np.arange(self.files_count)
        self.classes_count = len(classes)

        # to initialize transformations and shuffle indices
        self.on_epoch_end()

        print("get %d classes for %d files for %s" % (
            self.classes_count,
            self.files_count,
            'train' if _validation_data is None else 'validation'))

    def get_validation_generator(self):
        """ Return the validation generator if you've provided split factor """
        return self.__class__(
            nb_frames=self.nbframe,
            nb_channel=self.nb_channel,
            target_shape=self.target_shape,
            classes=self.classes,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            shuffle=self.shuffle,
            rescale=self.rescale,
            _validation_data=self.validation)

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        """ Called by Keras after each epoch """

        if self.transformation is not None:
            self._random_trans = []
            for i in range(self.files_count):
                self._random_trans.append(
                    self.transformation.get_random_transform(self.target_shape)
                )

        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(self.files_count / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        classes = self.classes
        shape = self.target_shape
        nbframe = self.nbframe

        labels = []
        images = []

        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        transformation = None

        for i in indexes:
            # prepare a transformation if provided
            if self.transformation is not None:
                transformation = self._random_trans[i]

            # video = random.choice(files)
            video = self.files[i]
            classname = video.split(os.sep)[-2]

#            create a label array and set 1 to the right column
            label = []
            col = classes.index(classname)
            label.append(1 if col==0 else 0)
            # label = [0,1]
            # label = np.array(label)

            if video not in self.__frame_cache:
                cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
                frames = []
                while True:
                    grabbed, frame = cap.read()
                    if not grabbed:
                        # end of video
                        break

                    # resize
                    frame = cv2.resize(frame, shape)

                    # use RGB or Grayscale ?
                    if self.nb_channel == 3:
                        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                        # frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                    else:
                        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

                    # to np
                    frame = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(
                        frame) * self.rescale

                    # keep frame
                    frames.append(frame)

                # Add 2 frames to drop first and last frame
                jump = len(frames)//(nbframe+2)


                # get only some images
                try:
                    frames = frames[jump::jump][:nbframe]
                except Exception as exception:
                    print(video)
                    raise exception

                # add to frame cache to not read from disk later
                if self.use_frame_cache:
                    self.__frame_cache[video] = frames
            else:
                frames = self.__frame_cache[video]

            # apply transformation
            if transformation is not None:
                frames = [self.transformation.apply_transform(
                    frame, transformation) for frame in frames]
                # print(frames)

            # add the sequence in batch
            images.append(frames)
            labels.append(label)

        return np.array(images), np.array(labels)
```

And the AudioGenerator is:

```
class AudioGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, ids, train_dir):
        'Initialization'
        self.ids = ids
        self.train_dir = train_dir

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        return 4

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        batch_id = self.ids[index]
        X = np.asarray(np.load(self.train_dir + str(batch_id*100) + '.npy'))
        Y = np.asarray(np.load(self.train_dir +'Y_'+ str(batch_id*100) + '.npy'))
        from sklearn import preprocessing
        if index==1:
          enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
          Y = Y.reshape(-1,1)
          enc.fit(Y)
          joblib.dump(enc,"/content/drive/My Drive/DeepFakeFiles/Encoder")
        enc = joblib.load("/content/drive/My Drive/DeepFakeFiles/Encoder")
        Y = Y.reshape(-1,1)  
        Y = enc.transform(Y).toarray()
        X = X.reshape(X.shape[0],X.shape[1],1)
        start=0
        batch,size= 4,4
        X_temp = X[start:batch,:]
        Y_temp = Y[start:batch,:]
        start = batch
        batch+=size
        return X_temp,Y_temp
```

And finally the data generator which generates the training data is:

```
import itertools
def create_data_generator(video_generator,audio_generator):
    while(True):
        _video_generator, _lvideo_generator = next(iter(video_generator))
        _audio_generator, _laudio_generator = next(iter(audio_generator))

        yield [_video_generator,_audio_generator], [_lvideo_generator,_laudio_generator]
```

It would be great if someone could help me with what the "second structure" means because I'm new with keras fit_generator(). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had that error, on a pretty different model type. I spent a lot of time trying to understand why it thought I had set sample_weights somehow. Actually in my case at least, that message was misleading.

I solved it by making sure my generator returned numpy arrays, not lists.

I did not dig too deep in it but it feels to me that lists and nested lists from generators seems to confuse TF somehow who then thinks some part of the labels are actually a third item describing sample weights.

I'd suggest explicitly creating np arrays as the outputs of your generator.